# How to give link to Second (Particular) page from all pages in MS Word?

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office

I have Table of Contents on Page number two and want to give link to same page from all pages of my document, If I created link in footer, it is not click-able.

So what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work here:

Insert a bookmark on the page you want to link to (or use a bookmark that is already there). Let's say it is called "xyz"

Insert a text box in the footer.

Insert the following field code

```
{ PAGEREF xyz \h }
```

where the { } are the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

Strange!

Only checked in Word 2010.